# Data Validation to allow any dollar amount and "N/A"

Tags: excel, vba

I used data validation to make the cell only allow decimals (so only amounts can be entered). I want to also allow "N/A" as a response. Anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Cheers,
Didi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the data validation dialog for the cell or range you want to check, select `Data Validation-->Custom` then for your cell or range enter the formula:

```
=OR(I4="N/A",ISNUMBER(I4))
```